# Failed to create GitHub Repository, Can't create user repository Can't parse GitHub response

Tags: android-studio, github, import

I want to share my project on GitHub from Android Studio using Import into Version Control then I got this notification, could someone help me with this? [VCS Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awrXv.png)

Comment: Can you describe all the steps you have taken before getting this response? this will help people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this too. I created new repo on github and pushed my code from git-bash. That works. Maybe it's a problem for some time.